# element not clickable when scrolling

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I’m encountering an issue with an element not being clickable when scrolling while working in Selenium/Java.

I am learning Selenium through the website https://saucelabs.com. After login, I naviagate the pricing page and in the pricing page I have to choose a monthly $50 plan and for that I need to click on subscribe for this plan. When I use the `xpath` and complete xpath in both cases it is not working. Below is my code.

How can I make the element clickable while scrolling?

```
public class assign1code {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("user-name")).sendKeys("standard_user");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("secret_sauce");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("react-burger-menu-btn")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//nav/a[text()='About']"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/header/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a/span")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 4100)"); // if the element is on bottom.
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"credits-calculator\"]/button")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor jsee = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jsee.executeScript("scroll(0, 4100)"); 
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"credits-calculator\"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor jseee = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jseee.executeScript("scroll(0, 6100)"); 
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'About' seems to be broken.